# Is $\textbf{BPP} \subseteq \textbf{P}^{\textbf{NP}}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Is it known that $\textbf{BPP} \subseteq \textbf{P}^{\textbf{NP}}$?

Comment: No, it’s not known. However, $\mathrm{BPP\subseteq MA\subseteq S_2P\subseteq ZPP^{NP}}$.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 9):

[Heller](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82186689.pdf) gives a relativized world where $BPP = EXP^{NP}$ which sits far outside of $P^{NP}$. Showing $BPP \neq EXP^{NP}$ unconditionally would in itself be considered a major breakthrough in derandomization.

Comment: What would $BPP\neq EXP^{NP}$ or $BPP\subseteq P^{NP}$ give in terms of lower bounds?